# How to reconnect to 'screen' session or start a new command

Tags: gnu-screen

Since I have started using `screen` to start text-mode (console) email client (namely `alpine`), I have never lost partially written email due to network disconnect.  Very useful.

However starting email client is now a bit involved:

1. Check if there is old session with `screen -list`
2. Depending on the previous step:

   - If there is one, reconnect with `screen -U -r <number>`
   - If there isn't one, start email client with `screen -U alpine`

How can I simplify these steps so that I can run only simple command (simple script), that is `start_or_reconnect alpine`?  We can assume that if there is more than one session active it is an error, or just use the first one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an explicit session name (`-S` option), and use `-RR` to reattach to an existing session or create one if there is none.

```
alias m='screen -S alpine -d -RR alpine'
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and stupid:

```
#!/bin/sh
ARG=`screen -list | grep Detached | awk '{print $1}'`
if [ -z "$ARG" ]; then
    screen -U alpine
else
    screen -U -r $ARG
fi
```